# Response for a class (RFC) metric tools for PHP

Tags: tools, metrics, php

Is there any tools to calculate Response for a class (RFC) metric for PHP?
Both [PhpMetrics](http://www.phpmetrics.org/documentation/index.html) and [PHP Depend](http://pdepend.org/documentation/software-metrics/index.html) don't support it.

RFC is related to Software Quality [[3](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/10000532)].